# Print Pass-through on Windows Server 2008 queues

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

We are migrating a number of print queues off a Windows 2000 server onto a 2008 server.  We send print jobs to these queues from a remote Unix box, typically just plain ascii text reports.  On the 2000 server these reports pass-through unaltered and print using the printers default page setting for orientation and font etc.  On the 2008 server (and on 2003) the page is reformatted and output in portrait, courier text, 80 columns.

Is there anyway I can force the file to pass through the queue unaltered? I have tried changing the print processor setting but to no avail.

Thanks.
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, needed to add a reg key *SimulatePassThrough* as per [MSKB article 150930](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150930)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar on a Windows 2003-based print server for a Customer with no problems. We've got a supplier who submits print jobs from a HP/UX machine to our W2K3 server, and we send them on to Zebra label printers. I've got the W2K3 machine exporting LPR queues (using the "Print Servces for Unix" LPR server) and have configured the particular queue the supplier uses with a "Generic / Text-only" driver in Windows.

AFAIK, the jobs they're submitting are being passed straight through to the Zebra without any reformatting being performed by the Windows spooler. (Put it this way: I've gotten no complaints and labels are printing alright...)

Comment: Thanks Evan, that isn't the solution though. I already do the very same thing for label printers we have and yes it does work just fine. However our problem is with regular HP laser printers, if we send raw PCL then that passes through OK but if it's plain ascii text the print processor ignores the default RAW format for whatever reason.  I have found the solution now, see my own answer.